Docker compose container on VirtualBox cannot write to VirtualBox shared folder
I am running a software (namely, immich) inside docker compose (plugin) container on a Debian virtualbox virtual machine (both host and guest Debian 12).
The guest has a shared folder owned by root:vboxsf. The root user is part of vboxsf group (I checked using groups root).
The problem is that the software running inside the docker container does not have write permissions in the shared folder, despite the docker compose is run by root who is part of vboxsf group that is the group which by default has complete access to the shared folder.
Shared folder permissions /media/media:
/media/
total 12K
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4.0K Sep 27 23:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root   4.0K Sep 27 22:59 ..
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4.0K Sep 27 23:10 media

Here is the error i receive from the software we are talking about (immich):
[Nest] 18  - 10/17/2024, 7:59:08 AM   ERROR [Api:StorageService] The "encoded-video" folder cannot be written to, please make sure the volume is mounted with the correct permissions

If I try to use another folder (e.g. /home/media) instead of the virtualbox shared folder /media/media, the software runs properly. Therefore, it is clear that the problem is with virtualbox and/or docker.
I then checked if it is really root running the docker container using ps aux | grep docker and I can confirm that yes, it is indeed run by root.
